# Basic cmake question on including a new class

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

Currently my project just has one BookPrinter.cpp file and the CMakeList.txt in its directory contains

```
add_executable(book_printer
    BookPrinter.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(book_printer
    ${MD_API_LIBRARIES}
    rt
    z
)
```

Now I want to add a new class "MyBookWrapper" with MyBookWrapper.h and MyBookWrapper.cpp in the same directory. I have `include BookWrapper.h` in my BookPrinter.cpp.

but when I compile I got this error

```
BookPrinter.cpp:blah blah blha incomprehensible code : undefined reference to `MyBookWrapper::Refresh()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I add to include this new MyBookWrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the *first* thing you should do is add `MyBookWrapper.cpp` to your `add_executable` statement.

What you have there is a linker error meaning that it can't locate the *code* for your new class, it has nothing to do with the header file.